# Default parameter value for splat operator in static method

Tags: php, php-7.2

I'm trying to rewrite some of the php functions into a standard class library as static methods so my development team can understand the php functions.

Here's what I currently have:

```
class StringUtil
{
    public static function sprintf ($format, $args = null, ... $_)
    {
        return sprintf($format,$args,$_);
    }
}
```

With this method declaration I should be able to utilize the `splat operator` correctly.

My problem is if there is no parameter usage past `$args` then the `splat operator` should fail as its declared as required.

What I'm looking for is something like this, with a `null` value passed as the default parameter for the `splat operator`:

```
class StringUtil
{
    public static function sprintf ($format, $args = null, ... $_ = null)
    {
        return sprintf($format,$args,$_);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use func_get_args() and vsprintf() bro

Comment: Yes im trying to mimic the exact functionality of sprintf as a static method. is there a solution for which I asked for?

Comment: Maybe I can use func get args with this static method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class StringUtil
{
    public static function sprintf($format)
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $fmt  = array_shift($args);

        return vsprintf($fmt, $args);
    }
}
```

UPD:

```
class StringUtil
{
    public static function sprintf($fmt)
    {
        return call_user_func_array('sprintf', func_get_args());
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i need to be precisely using sprintf inside the method